# Is Apache NiFi Registry(0.5.0) Support in Windows OS

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi-registry

As per the below documentation it does not shows "Windows" in the supported OS for the application system requirement. 
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/administration-guide.html#how-to-install-and-start-nifi-registry
But I can able to start the NiFi Registry in the windows and able to work on it. 
What will be issues I will face If I works NiFi Registry on Windows.

Comment: if it is worried, use the docker.

Comment: Yes, we can but we need to know about its actual functionality of the NiFi registry package @Lamanus

Comment: No one guarantees.